# FSSM gem complaints when running a Compass watch

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using Sass and Compass for CSS work but recently since I've installed RVM and the latest version of Ruby I'm getting the following notice when running a compass watch:

```
$ compass watch
/Users/ian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/fssm-0.2.7/lib/fssm/support.rb:40: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
FSSM -> An optimized backend is available for this platform!
FSSM ->     gem install rb-fsevent
```

I'm running OS X Snow Leopard but I found [this article](http://frontendbook.com/fixing-sass-watch-on-os-x-lion) and followed the instructions there installing both fssm and rb-fsevent but that didn't make any difference.

Can anyone suggest how I may surpress this warning each time I put a watch on my stylesheets?

Comment: As an update, it looks like the rb-fsevent gem wasn't installed in the right location. I've made sure it is now and it's fixed the last two lines of the warning but the first like regarding fssm still remains. I've also tried removing and re-installing that gem but with no effect.